# Redirect page doesn't automatically close after successful OAuth authorization

Tags: azure, mobile, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services

I am following the below tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users . I set up the OAuth (via Google) and the created the windows 10 app. 
When I click on authenticate button, it takes me to Google site and authenticates me. Then it redirects me to a happy page. This happy page has not buttons. Closing the happy page gives me a [User cancelled login exception]. There is no way to proceed ahead after this. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> I set up the OAuth (via Google) and the created the windows 10 app. When I click on authenticate button, it takes me to Google site and authenticates me. Then it redirects me to a happy page. This happy page has not buttons. Closing the happy page gives me a [User cancelled login exception].

Per my understanding, you are creating a UWP project. I followed [Add authentication to your Windows app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users) and [Configure App Service to use Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication), then I download the quick start project to check this issue. I could login successfully with my Google account as follows:

[image]

Here is my code sample, you could refer to [AzureMobileApp-UWP](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AzureMobileApp-UWP).